# How can I share my home-machine disk space with a networked client

Tags: linux, ubuntu, fedora, network-shares

I have an account on a remote machine which I need to use frequently. I do not have big storage quota there, so I have to copy a portion of my repository or delete some other stuff form there while working. How can I attach my home machine folder with remote machine so that I can read/write to it? Using scp frequently is irritating me. [Making a very sad face]

If I have two accounts on two different machines A and B, and I want to attach A's home with B, can I do it? I do not have super-user privileges on any of these machines.

OS : Linux (Ubuntu) Client / Linux (Fedora) Server

UPDATE : Last three lines are added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many guides out there explaining how to do this, you aren't specifying which OS and distro you are using, so it is difficult to point you to a particular guide or instructions.

However, just google for $YOURDISTRO and "samba setup" and you should find what you need.
There are many other network filesystems that will satisfy your requirements (NFS and others), but SAMBA is the most common and is fairly easy to setup and well supported. Also worth checking sshfs if you already have ssh setup...

Comment: sshfs looks like I got what I need. And I have update my question.